# Gradle provided JAR dependency not working as expected

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I've been stuck on this problem all day, I'm hoping someone can help me get my program running.

I am building an Annotation Processor for Android, it currently has two modules: "mymodule" and "mymodule-compiler"

mymodule-compiler depends on mymodule:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':mymodule')
  ...
}
```

mymodule uses the netflix "provided" plugin for Android:

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.provided-base'

dependencies {
  provided 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
}
```

This actually works perfectly, however when I run my compiler unit test suite, a lot of tests fail because the Android dependency specified is v4.1.1.4 and I actually need v6.0. v6.0 is not available on Maven (and looks like it never will be because Google haven't updated it since 2012).

I found out that the Android SDK provides a "Unit Test" JAR version of Android for each release, which is the entire SDK "stubbed out". I assume the versions on Maven are stubbed out too(?). I can easily grab that JAR and put it in my project under libs/.

Now when I update the mymodule gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  provided files('libs/android.jar')
}
```

My project still compiles correctly and I can see v23 files! However, when I run my unit tests, I see the following error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
  at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
  at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
  at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
  at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:205)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:188)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

It shouldn't matter that the Android JAR is stubbed out because I never execute Android code, I only need it for imports.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm seeing and how I could fix this?

EDIT 1: More info:

If I remove the Android dependencies from mymodule entirely, and instead put the following into mymodule-compiler.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  testCompile files('libs/android.jar')
  ...
}
```

All my tests will pass. This is obviously not a fix though, as 'mymodule' does need the Android dependency.

EDIT 2:

Doing the same test as EDIT 1, but using the netflix provided scope instead of testCompile works too. If I use the provided scope in both projects though, I get the same Stub! exception.

Comment: are you sure you wanted to write "netflix"?

Comment: 'nebula.provided-base' is a netflix plugin, it could be something to do with that. I honestly don't know what the problem is.

Comment: gradle does support 'provided' natively. I don't know why you use a plugin. I asked for netflix because I thought of the poular video provider and didn't know the plugin.

Comment: If you use the Android plugin you get provided, but the netflix plugin is for java projects. https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin

Comment: So your code is not executed in android, but in an JVM? Where do you expect the provided classes to come from?

Comment: mymodule is a library that an android app uses. The compiler runs with javac and of course has no Android references, but the tests need Android imports (e.g. android.os.SparseArray, etc) otherwise they fail. Tests should work because of the provided scope, but they currently don't (seemingly because it's a JAR, it *did* work with the maven dependency, except for the few that need v6.0 of Android).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101498/discussion-between-f43nd1r-and-bradley-campbell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Worked out together with OP]

The local jar contains additional classes over the maven jar which seem to interfere.
To get it working delete these from the jar (specifically in this case: all junit classes).

Comparison of the two jars (left is maven jar, right is local jar):[image: comparison]